# Prompt message "Please Update" to fill one cell when another cell has data entered

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible in google sheets to get a prompt message to fill one cell when another cell has data entered. The message just has to be "Please Update"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(B1="";;"Please Update")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to retain the formula even if any data is entered into the cell with the formula?

Comment: you mean to have that formula even after you would type something in C2? possible but only with script

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. What script do I put in for this?